# ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 2: Invalid use of group function

Tags: sql, group-by

There are two tables

1. marks (student_id,marks,course)
2. Teacher (teacher_name, course)

q. Write a query to find the name of the teacher teaching the course with the highest average.

My code:

```
select teacher_name
from teacher t
where t.Course = (select m.course
                from marks m
                group by m.course
                having avg(marks)=max(avg(marks)));
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @GMB we should create a tag `Homework`...

Comment: @VDWWD: actually that *could* be a good idea, so we could attach the best practices to the tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed filter with a subquery. In that case you need to aggregate the marks table by courses, sort by average marks and keep the first record only:

```
select teacher_name
from teacher t
where t.course = (
    select m.course
    from marks m
    group by m.course
    order by avg(m.mark) desc
    limit 1
)
```

The exact syntax for `limit` varies accross databases (in SQL Server, you would use `select top 1 ... from ... group by ... order by`).

Side note: it is not necessarily a good idea to have a column name that has the same name as the table (`marks`). I renamed that column to `mark` in the query.

Comment: using order by clause and limit worked. Thank you so much. what was wrong with having clause here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the usage of " = " for an array. Also db scheme is wrong, create a table Course, and fk to the teacher and marks table. Then you can use

```
    select teacher_name from teacher t where t.course_id in 
( select m.course_id from marks m GROUP BY m.course_id ...)
```